# Object sharing in weblogic cluseted/non-clustered managed servers in domain

Tags: weblogic

i am new to weblogic and trying to understand the sharing of session/object within managed servers

Can I share object/state/session only within cluster or the whole domain

1 domain
1 cluster with server1, server2 ,server3

Server4, Server5, Server6 are non clustered managed server.

So any session/state/object (on clustered session, either 1, 2 or 3) would be shared by all managed server with domain (1-6) or only within clustered servers 1-3 and will not be shared to servers 4-5

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring sounds like the services provided by Oracle-Coherence. Coherence lets you pick what servers you want to share specific data on. It does object/session and a lot more. Coherence data is only shared with servers configured to receive said data and hence this is the best option for you. More on Coherence is here.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/coherence/overview/index-087514.html

If you are looking for an open-source free alternative, you could check this post.

[open source alternatives to oracle coherence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163410/open-source-alternatives-to-oracle-coherence)

FYI, just to put it out there, you can do so in your application with using external tools but it would generally not be worth the time, money or effort for this.

Comment: Right! Coherence is integrated with WebLogic, and included as part of WebLogic Suite.